# How to find the cause of EHOSTUNREACH in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, system-calls, ehostunreach

I have a NodeJS program with many complex dependencies.

It was occasionally crashing with `EHOSTUNREACHABLE`, so I added a `process.on('uncaughtException' ...` handler.

Neither the original crash, nor the caught error give any indication of where the problem occurs, as it is an async exception, thrown from NodeJS code (rather than application code).

```
{ [Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH]
  code: 'EHOSTUNREACH',
  errno: 'EHOSTUNREACH',
  syscall: 'connect' }
```

Is there a way of finding more details via the syscall which NodeJS is making?  Ideally, I would like to know the remote IP address which is unreachable.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use longjohn https://github.com/mattinsler/longjohn to get longer stack traces for your exception.